# How can I stop PowerShell integrated terminal from appearing on VScode startup?

Tags: bash, powershell, visual-studio-code

I use Git Bash as both internal and external terminal and basically never use powershell. I've tried setting up VScode accordingly, and here's my settings.json:

```
{
  "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    
    "PowerShell": null,
    "Command Prompt": null,
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash",
      "path": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
  "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "Git Bash",
  "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false,
  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
}
```

Now Ctrl+` for me launches Git Bash in integrated terminal, which was my goal, but VScode still launches either nothing or powershell upon startup, which is annoying. Is there any way to stop VScode from doing that?

Comment: It's a known problem in v1.60.0, scheduled to be fixed in v1.60.1